# Detener el audio de flutter_tts cuando la app este en segundo plano

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy trabajando una app para Android utilizando flutter, tengo diferentes textos que se leen con el paquete flutter_tts, cuando minimizo la app o pasa a segundo plano, el audio sigue reproduciéndose, quiero que se detenga pero no logro hacerlo.

Así inicializo flutter_tts:

```
    this.flutterTts = FlutterTts();
    
    flutterTts.setStartHandler(() {
      print("Hablando");
      setState(() {
        this.isSpeaking = true;
        this.ttsState = TtsState.playing;
      });
    });
    flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() {
      print("Completado");
      setState(() {
        this.isSpeaking = false;
        this.ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });
    flutterTts.setErrorHandler((msg) {
      print("Error: $msg");
      setState(() {
        this.isSpeaking = false;
        this.ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });
```

Y estas son las funciones para reproducir y detener el audio respectivamente:

```
    Future _speak(String texto) async {
      await this.flutterTts.setLanguage("es-MX");
      await this.flutterTts.setVoice({"name": "Paulina", "locale": "es-MX"});
      await this.flutterTts.setPitch(1);
      await this.flutterTts.speak(texto);
    }

  Future _stop() async {
    var result = await this.flutterTts.stop();
    if (result == 1)
      setState(() {
        this.isSpeaking = false;
        this.ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
  }
```

encontré el método para detectar cuando la app esta en segundo plano:

```
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        _stop();
      }
    }
```

pero no me funciona, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: que error te sale? el setState no funciona si la app está en background

Comment: @diegoveloper no me aparece ningún error, simplemente no me funciona detener el audio, sigue reproduciéndose.